# Unable to locate element by div class

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Trying to check if the element set focus to using class header matching by text and getting error unable to locate the element. I know the header title which is 'My Details'  in this example, and using this title, how to locate the element?

```
<div class="attribute-group-header card__header">
<h3 class="attribute-group-title card__header-title">My Details</h3>
</div>


 Element should be focused      //div[contains(.,'My Details')
```

Comment: you may try: $(".attribute-group-header card__header .attribute-group-title card__header-title")

Comment: Nguyen - did you mean to replace the dot inside the contains with this? Didn't work though, same error

Comment: What @AnNguyen has given you in the comment is a css selector - e.g. if you try it, the locator should be `css:.attribute-group-header card__header .attribute-group-title card__header-title`. Have in mind though class selectors tend to return multiple results (a lot of elements in the page may have the same classes).

Comment: @Sarah what exactly is the problem now? The title of the question is how to locate through a class, you continue the element is not located through it, and tried with its text; the xpath in the locator looks ok, it should match the element. So what issue are you having - the element is still not located with it, **or** the kw `Element should be focused` is failing as it is not in focus? Please edit your question so its clearer what's the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Todor.  You were right, with the css selector my test returned multiple objects, that was the reason I was trying to locate the element by its text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate the `h3` in your example code, use this xpath `//h3[contains(text(),'My Details')]`

To locate the `div` which has `card__header` in `class`, use this xpath `//div[contains(@class,'card__header')]`

Comment: Thanh -  Now with  //h3[contains(text(),'My Details')]   my element is located but I am getting error - Element is not set to focus. My test is trying to validate when user clicks on a side menu link the specific link is accessed on the Page. I can't seem to find the right keyword to validate that the user navigated to the link section. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine with this keyword and the X-path reference. Thank you all for guiding me to find the solution

```
 Element should be enabled     //h3[contains(text(),'${MyLinkText}')]
```